# Suppose $X_1, X_2$ are independent and uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, 1]$

Tags: probability

What is the joint pdf of $X_1$ and $X_2$ conditioned on the event $X_1 \leq X_2$?

I know that the event of $X_1 \leq X_2$ is of probability $1/2$, but I don't know how to proceed exactly.

Comment: What is the probability of the event $X_1=X_2$?

Comment: @angryavian ok, so the conditional pdf should just be 1/2. But I don't really know how to justify it being uniform. Could you explain this a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

We have $X_1|X_2\sim U(0,\,X_2)$, so if $X_2=x_2$ the PDF of $X_1$ is $x_2^{-1}$ on $[0,\,x_2]$. Assuming you know [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), the joint pdf is $x_2^{-1}[x_1\le x_2]$ on $[0,\,1]^2$, viz. $$\int_{0\le x_1\le x_2\le1}\frac{dx_1dx_2}{x_2}=\int_0^1\frac{dx_2}{x_2}\int_0^{x_2}dx_1=\int_0^1dx_2=1.$$